# putting mysql_fetch_array with the same result set within two loops doesn't work

Tags: php

The first loop does well,but the second isn't. For example:

```
$sql = "select * from table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //some code
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //some code
}
```

I just want to know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**after I answered I've done some more research and posted the correct version in the edit below**

Because it's the way array iterators work in PHP, resetting the pointer should do the trick:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //some code
}
// reset($result); - won't work with mysql_query() result
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   //some code
}
```

Read more on the [reset() function here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

**EDIT:** after more research I found I was wrong - use `mysql_data_seek`:

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
```

Comment: This is not correct, reset() accepts array, here you provided resource because $result is resource (return of mysql_query)

Comment: @JasonOOO Sorry, I have updated my answer, just found this out myself

Comment: Warning: reset() [function.reset]: Passed variable is not an array or object

Answer (score 1):

Once you fetch all data of result set through first while loop then pointer goes to the last record and thus it won't fetch anything in the second while loop. You need to set pointer back to the first record before passing it again to while loop.

Just update your code like this:

```
$sql = "select * from table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //some code
}

mysql_data_seek(0); // Add this line

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `$result` like this:

```
$sql = "select * from table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$result2 = $result;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //some code
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
  //some code
}
```

Comment: It should work, but I think it would be better to iterate over the $result and copying the content first to an array and not the result object

Comment: yes, but I think OP wants to know how to do that, copying to array is better